# How to get the index of clicked item of filtered ListView in Android?

Tags: android, listview

My question is an extended part of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18685232/adding-custom-data-to-listview-arrayadapter-items) question.

I need to get the particular model from the clicked listitem in `ListView` when the `ListView` is filtered.

This is my datamodel.

```
public class ProductListModel{
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ProductName;
    }
    public ProductListModel(int ProductId, String ProductName) {            
        ProductId = ProductId;
        ProductName = ProductName;
    }
    public int getProductId() {
        return ProductId;
    }
    public void setProductId(int ProductId) {
        ProductId = ProductId;
    }
    public String getProductName() {
        return ProductName;
    }
    public void setProductName(String ProductName) {
        ProductName = ProductName;
    }
    int ProductId;
    String ProductName;
}
```

The array I'm fetching from database.

```
ProductListModel[] slm=new ProductListModel[count];
```

I have an `ArrayAdapter` like this

```
ArrayAdapter<ProductListModel> ad=new ArrayAdapter<ProductListModel>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, slm);
```

and my `ItemClickListener` is also working fine and giving me everything it must provide.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),slm[position].ProductName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

but when I'm filtering the adapter to show filtered data only, `onItemClick()` is giving some other values which is not clicked.

I suppose this is happening because row position of items are changing when we filter the data and hence its not providing the original position to get the productid of product clicked.

Can any one help me to get the productid after we filter the `ListView`?

Comment: use Adapter.getItem() method

Comment: Thanks @pskink. never thought of getting data back from adapter itself. how do I accept this as answer???

Comment: this is the only way of getting the adapter's item,  never use any other workarounds

Answer (score 1):

I have a tricky way..
keep the original list as global variable in main class.
List  orgList;
you can tag the item name in the view in its `getView()` in the adapter class.
and in `lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {`

```
   @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
            long id) {
        String name = agr1.getTag().tostring();
        //orgList original item position from name  variable and use it
         orgList.indexOf(name) will do that.
    }
});`
```

Hope this will solve your problem. I dont know any other better method.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Jithu. I didn't try your method yet as Adapter.getItem() method solved my problem for now. but will definitely try this one  once I'm through with this project.

Comment: ok.. I know getItem() will solve your problem. But i used to keep getItem() empty.. thats why I thought like this. getItem() is the correct method. no need to try out this.